# How to I stop Chrome from updating when it is first installed?

Tags: google-chrome

There are a lot of answer here describing how to disable chrome update AFTER it is installed. What I couldn't figure out is how to stop Chrome from updating DURING installation. For example, I was trying to install 30.0.1599.10 for debugging but it always update me to the latest version.

Comment: Unplug ethernet while installing?

Comment: The installer that you normally downloaded from Google is just a 800kb executable that is used to connect to the internet to download the real installer.

Comment: Here's the alternate installers : https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en